# JSON images on Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, image

I need convert the string to image and I got this error:

"Error cannot convert value of type String? to expected argument type 'Data'"

```
    let url = URL(string: "http://******************")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            print("solicitud fallida \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {

            print("recibimos respuesta")

            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let nombre = json["nombre"]
                    self.urllabel.text = nombre

                    let backimg = json["fondo"]
                    self.imgfondo.image = UIImage(data: backimg)
                }
```

Comment: `json["fondo"]` contains a string. Why are you trying to pass it to be method that expects Data?

Answer (score 0):

You should have you json serialized as ["string":Any] and cast the values as String and Data later on. If are you sure that "fondo" is of type Data in your backend, then this should work

Like this:

```
 if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any?] {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let nombre = json["nombre"] as? String{
                    self.urllabel.text = nombre
                }


                if let backimg = json["condo"] as? Data{ //Is this of type Data in you backend? //Data is the same as NSData prior to Swift 3
                    self.imgfondo.image = UIImage(data: backimg)
                }

            }
```

The reason your solution didn't work was because you tried to make an image from a string, when you should have passed in a type of NSData.

Comment: It's Swift 3, do not use `NSData`, use `Data`.

Comment: And it's clear from the error that `json["fondo"]` contains `String`, not `Data`.

Comment: The error string comes because he serializes he's JSON as [string:string] and not ["string":Any] as I have pointed in my answer! It's not clear what data he actually get from he's backed, but if it is of type Data my answer is correct.

Comment: Then that would cause another error if `json["fondo"]` actually contained `Data` when it is declared as `String`. Further proof that it really does contain `String`. Your answer will simply cause the `if let` to fail and skip over the setting of the image.

Comment: Though I am making the assumption that the error is on the `UIImage(data: backimg)` line and not the `let backimg = json["fondo"]` line.

Comment: That makes sense to me also. As I have pointed in my answer, OP needs to make sure that it is Data he get's from he's backend and not some string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are able to successfully pass unwrapping your JSON response as `[String: String]`, which means you have to convert your image string to a data object. It is not already data. Just to make sure - the string you are getting back is a data string and not a url string for an image?

I'm answering below assuming that it is a data string.

```
if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: String] {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      if let nombre = json["nombre"] as? String {
        self.urllabel.text = nombre
      }

      if let backImgString = json["condo"] as? String {
        if let backImgData = backImgString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? NSData {
          self.imgfondo.image = UIImage(data: backImgData)
        } else {
        //handle error here
        }
      } else {
      //handle error here
      }
    }
}
```